# Use Class from a local package

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

Here is my folder structure:

```
application
  ml_model (local package)
     __init__.py
     rf_forest.py

  custom_transformer.py
  sample_test.py
```

custom_transformer.py contains

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class FeatureTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        # replacing missing cabins with U (for Uknown)
        x['week'] = x.week_starting.dt.isocalendar().week
        x['month'] = x.week_starting.dt.month
        x = x.set_index('week_starting')
        x['week'] = x['week'].astype(int)
        x['date_week'] = x['date_week'].astype(int)
        x['store_number'] = x['store_number'].astype(int)
        x['category'] = x['category'].astype(int)
        x['vendor_number'] = x['vendor_number'].astype(int)
        x['item_number'] = x['item_number'].astype(int)

        return x
```

rf_forest.py contains

```
import pickle
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
from datetime import date, datetime
import util.db_crud as db
from custom_transformer import FeatureTransformer
import util.predictions as predict
import os
with open("model.pkl", 'rb') as file:
```

And throws `Can't get attribute 'FeatureTransformer' on <module '__main__' '` error

When importing FeatureTransformer class from the same level I am able to import it correctly

E.g. sample_test.py contains

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from custom_transformer import FeatureTransformer
    with open("model.pkl", 'rb') as file:
```

I tried many permutations by moving the class at various levels but not able to import it correctly?
is the structure in-correct or I missing very fundamental concepts of class imports

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues which you can have a look at

1. `custom_transformer.py` is not at the same level as `rf_forest.py`. So you have to import it from one step back in the hierarchy.
2. `with open("model.pkl", 'rb') as file:` also do not seems correct in current context.

As I do not have a complete setup. Maybe these pointers help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks, I tried moving custom_transformer.py to the same level as rf_forest.py but still not able to import the call getting the same error    Can't get attribute 'FeatureTransformer'

About the second point, same  code is working on sample test python file , I believe it's not related

Comment: Try importing as `from application.custom_transformer import FeatureTransformer`. See if you are able to imprt now

Comment: tried importing from the root folder as well and still the same error, I also tried multiple combinations by importing to various levels still getting the same error